# missing a reference after deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, twilio, iis-8

i developed a project in vs2010, and it includes external libraries such as Twilio.
i downloaded and installed the libraries by nuget. i can find the dll in the bin folder of the project. it works fine by debbuging it in visual studio.

then i copied the project in my remote server with iis8, and when i call the url www.xxxxxxx.com/myproject/default.aspx, it can't find the Twilio reference

```
 The type or namespace name 'Twilio' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

all twilio dlls are in the "bin" folder of the project, and the dlls copy local property are set to "true".

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is the folder set as an application in IIS on the remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install a .dll with Nuget Manager, the manager automatically adds the .dll to your registry. When you copy it to a new computer you need to reregister the dll. I use RegAsm.